# MGS 5 TPP: the game starts forever at PC

Tags: steam, metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I am starting Metal Gear Solid 5 TPP, Steam version... Skipping all the screens I finally press "Continue" and that screen lasts forever. I am able to paginate through advices, the loading circular icon is rotating, but nothing further and there is no way to return to the previous screen also.

Any idea how to fix that?

The first time this happened Sep 9 and it continues Sep 11 still, so it lasts 2 full days already. I tried it with internet both on and off. All up to date. The progress is 11%. Windows 7 64 bit. Everything was fine prior that day.

Comment: Tried verifying game cache on Steam or just reinstalling local files? Be sure you back up your saves before you do so.

Comment: Corrupted cache was the issue. I verified and fixed it successfully. Thank you!!

Answer (score -2):

i think u should re-install the game and contact the msg support . Maybe on their website ?? re-install the game ... i think that will fix it.